# Mostrar return en otro método

Tags: java

Quisiera usar el valor del return en el método main para imprimirlo, pero no sé cómo invocarlo.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
int valorDevuelto = operacion(numero);
        System.out.println("La suma de puntos es: "+valorDevuelto);
}
public static int operacion (int numero){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int tiradas, cara, i, numeroF = 0;

        System.out.print("Introduca cuantas tiradas quiere realizar: ");
        tiradas = sc.nextInt();

        for (i = 0; i<tiradas; i++){
            cara = (int) (Math.random()*6)+1;
            numeroF += cara;
            numero = numeroF;

            System.out.println("Los puntos de la tirada número "+(i+1)+" son: "+cara);
        }
        return numero;
    }
```

Comment: no está muy claro lo que pides. Por favor, [edita](/edit) tu pregunta para explicar en más detalle el funcionamiento que deseas y elq ue estás consiguiendo ahora mismo. Un saludo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes llamar directamente a la función. Algo así:

```
System.out.println("La suma de puntos es: " + operacion(1));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha funcionado! Me podrías explicar por qué hay que usar un 1? Un saludo.

Comment: @h3h3h3h3 Ese `1` es el **argumento** que le envías al método. Puede ser 1, 2,3... Cualquier numero te vale.

Comment: Claro, lo del 1 se lo he pasado por pasar, tú ahí le pasarías el número que tú quieras.

Answer (score 1):

Declara una variable del mismo tipo que el return y asignale el método:

```
int valorDevuelto = operacion(parametro);
```

Comment: Gracias por responder! Pero al poner eso me salta un error en diciendo que tengo que crear la variable en el main

Comment: La variable parametro? Es una que use yo solo para poder explicar el funcionamiento. Como dijo Lombarda Arda, vos deberias usar cualquier numero entero.